# After adding service worker node in chrome extension manifest ExtensionSidebarPane is stop showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I try to add service worker in chrome extension.ExtensionSidebarPane stop working.
I want service worker and ExtensionSidebarPane both together but adding service worker break ExtensionSidebarPane. I provided all the details and code that I used in this extension felled by folder structure.

This is the folder structure of chrome extension

```
TEST-EXTENSION
│   manifest.json
│   ServiceWorker.js
│   
└─── devtools
        devtools.html
        devtools.js
        main.html
```

Here is the sample of each files contains of
**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Sample 1",
    "short_name": "Sample 1",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "Test Extesnion",
    "devtools_page": "devtools/devtools.html",
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab", "offscreen"],
    "minimum_chrome_version": "88",
    "background": {
     "service_worker": "ServiceWorker.js"
    }
}
```

**ServiceWorker.js**

```
console.log('background service worker Loaded!');
```

**Devtools.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="./devtools.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Devtools.js**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane('Sample', function (sidebar) {
  sidebar.setPage('/devtools/main.html');
  sidebar.setHeight('300px');
});
```

**Main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, This test project is working !!!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Chrome version**
[image]

When I remove this service worker lines from manifest file

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "ServiceWorker.js"
}
```

ExtensionSidebarPane is properly visible and working.
But when I add service worker config ExtensionSidebarPane stop showing in inspect window.
I think it might having issue with chrome update cause it works fine before I updated chrome browser.
After removing service worker from manifest
[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong .??
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, report it in https://crbug.com.

Comment: I reported this bug to Chromium, track progress here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1496738